# Should we ask people to post a reference everytime possible?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

The only answer to [this Security SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128503/does-oracles-guardedstring-protect-sensitive-data-against-heap-or-memory-dumps) does answer the question but doesn't add any relevant reference.
The person doesn't have a medal for the topic so I wasn't sure if we should accept the answer without any reference just for the sake of accuracy. I was wondering if this should be a general thing. I find it a good way to ensure that an inaccurate answer is not marked as accepted just because it aligns with the OP's thought process/requirement.

Comment: My problem with the linked answer is that it lacks an explanation (and not so much the missing references). A yes/no answer doesn't help OP understand their misconceptions. I think we should read most yes/no questions with an implicit "If so/not, why?" and don't accept an answer that provides just a solution without clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately "we" do not accept answers. The person asking the question does. That's not where the community has its leverage.

What *we* can do to maintain the quality of answers on this site is to comment (which you've done) and to vote.

So, yes, we should ask people to provide sources and references when it is suitable. "Every time" is a little much, but I get your point.